# best way to copy complex directory structure file

Tags: linux

As we know, we could use rsync, tar or cp to transfer directory or files on NFS file system or different server.
Just be curious that which way is best to transfer complex directory?

Or writing a customized c program would be simple and fast to copy or create the link directory structure tree.

Comment: Might be more appropriate at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix filesystem management

Comment: We want to construct the directories tree before running some regression. So we need copy or create it and take the productivity into account. Not about filesystem management such as backup etc.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is use `rsync`. It is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the amount of data sent over the network by **sending only the differences between the source files and the existing files in the destination**. `rsync` is widely used for backups and mirroring and as an improved copy command for everyday use.

The utility of command `tar` is: "designed to store and extract files from an archive file known as a tarfile". Not to do a transfer between servers.. And `cp` is more simple than rsync command. Replace all the files in the destination.

About program customized in C, i think that It is difficult to optimize something that has already been optimized.

Comment: That said, if this is a one-time transfer, then `rsync` won't gain you much, as everything needs to be transferred, anyway. But if you are trying to keep two trees in sync, `rsync` (or maybe `unison` if updates might happen in either place) is definitely the way to go. Also, `tar`, `cp`, etc. don't have the "to another system" bits built in, so you have to also use `ssh` or something, so `rsync` definitely has that advantage...

Comment: You can make `rsync` between local files without ssh connection.